# VB.NET WinForms Optimization Makes Startup Radically Slower

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, performance

We're constructing 29 user controls (each containing many other standard and user controls) inside of a Load event handler on Form.

With optimization disabled (either in Debug mode or inside the Advanced Compiler Settings in Release mode) this takes about 7 seconds. With optimization enabled, this take about 50 seconds. This only happens on one of our non-internet connected lab machines; the startup time or release and debug is roughly the same on my machine. We're targeting .NET Framework 4.5 x64 from Visual Studio 2015.

Using a remote debugger and pausing periodically, it appears this is being caused by the JIT using a ton of CPU time before the code instantiates each user control. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Stack trace of JIT function which seems to be taking most of the time:

```
clrjit.dll!THX_NColBestCoverage(struct tagNCOLLIFETIME *,struct tagNCOLREGION *,class hashBv *,unsigned int,unsigned int,int *,struct CI_TAG *)
clrjit.dll!THX_NColDeterminePhysregAvail(struct tagNCOLLIFETIME *,struct tagNCOLREGION *,class hashBv *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct tagSYM *,int *,int *,struct CI_TAG *)
clrjit.dll!THX_NColProcessCandidateRegion(struct tagNCOLLIFETIME *,struct tagNCOLREGION *,struct tagNCOLREGION *,struct tagNCOLUSEBENEFITS *,struct tagTUPLE *,int,struct tagNCOLPHYSREGAVAILS *,struct CI_TAG *)
clrjit.dll!THX_NColor(struct tagFUNC *,struct CI_TAG *)
clrjit.dll!THX_dop2_CodegenUpdate(struct tagFUNC *,struct CI_TAG *)
clrjit.dll!THX_dop2(class JitContext *,struct CI_TAG *,unsigned char * *,unsigned int *)
clrjit.dll!PreJit::compileMethod(class ICorJitInfo *,struct CORINFO_METHOD_INFO *,unsigned int,unsigned char * *,unsigned long *)
[Managed to Native Transition]
```

Comment: Without seeing the code in the load handler it is difficult to speculate.  One possibility, since this is 64 bit, is the infamous exception eating that happens in the load handler.  Is the code wrapped in a Try-Catch block to detect exceptions?  As a workaround, you code decorate the method with a `<MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)>' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm a little confused as to your actual question. Are you trying to figure out why it takes so much longer when you use the optimizer?

If so, my answer is that the optimizer is taking up CPU (as you said) because it has to optimize each and every piece of information and data being pushed in and out of the application and even with a seemingly small amount of code, you have to keep in mind that if you call or load something, whether it be a function or calling another object from elsewhere, it has to make that work as well as possible. And rather than doing all this at run-time as the object/function/whatever is needed, it simply optimizes all of it before you can even use anything.